# Feature preprocessing of both continuous and categorical variables (of integer type) with scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

The main goals are as follows:

1. Apply `StandardScaler` to continuous variables
2. Apply `LabelEncoder` and `OnehotEncoder` to categorical variables

The continuous variables need to be scaled, but at the same time, a couple of categorical variables are also of integer type. Applying `StandardScaler` would result in undesired effects.

On the flip side, the `StandardScaler` would scale the integer based categorical variables, which is also not what we want.

Since continuous variables and categorical ones are mixed in a single `Pandas` DataFrame, what's the recommended workflow to approach this kind of problem?

The best example to illustrate my point is the [Kaggle Bike Sharing Demand](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bike-sharing-demand/data) dataset, where `season` and `weather` are integer categorical variables

Comment: As `StandardScalar` works column-wise, I dont think it will do anything to the one-hot encoded variables. Have you tried doing the above for that single Dataframe? Have you found the behaviour you seemed to be having trouble with?

Comment: One-hot-encoded variables are just the same as ones of integer type. If you have them concatenated together, why would you expect them doing things any differently? If they do behave the same way, what do you think would happen if there is a variable that's not categorical but numeric and has a value of either 1 or 0, and then use the scaler on it?

Comment: I tried, apparently it did scale everything regardless of what values they assumed. Could you please apply `StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)` on that Bike dataset and tell me otherwise?

Comment: Oh Sorry, I was confused between MinMaxScaler and StandardScaler. MinMaxScaler wont change the 1, 0, but StandardScaler would (zero mean and unit variance). Sorry again.

Comment: You can use http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py as an example to union the different features.

Comment: @VivekKumar never mind. I actually appreciate it a lot that you point out the differences​ between the two. FeatureUnion seems promising. Didn't know that and will definitely take a closer look. :)

Answer (score 27):

Check out the [`sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper`](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) meta-transformer. Use it as the first step in your pipeline to perform column-wise data engineering operations:

```
mapper = DataFrameMapper(
  [(continuous_col, StandardScaler()) for continuous_col in continuous_cols] +
  [(categorical_col, LabelBinarizer()) for categorical_col in categorical_cols]
)
pipeline = Pipeline(
  [("mapper", mapper),
  ("estimator", estimator)]
)
pipeline.fit_transform(df, df["y"])
```

Also, you should be using `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer` instead of a list of `[LabelEncoder(), OneHotEncoder()]`.

Comment: `sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper` is awesome and definitely worth checking out. Thank you for letting me know it. But according to the documentation,`LabelBinarizer` should be used in the situation where you have a target variable with multiple values, as opposed to multiple variables each having a set of different values, right? Don't know if I get it across or not.

Comment: The `LabelBinarizer` is the right choice for encoding string columns - it will first translate strings to integers, and then binarizes those integers to bit vectors. It does it all in one go. No need to divide this "workflow" between two transformer steps (ie. `LabelEncoder` plus `OneHotEncoder`). Just give it a try with real data, and you'll love it.

Comment: what exactly does "estimator" mean here?

Comment: @tbone In the context of Scikit-Learn pipelines, the last step of a pipeline aka "final_estimator" is some sort of model - a regressor or a classifier

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the ColumnTransformer in scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,LabelBinarizer

numeric_columns=list(X.select_dtypes('float64').columns)
categorical_columns=list(X.select_dtypes('int64').columns)

pipeline=ColumnTransformer([
    ('num',StandardScaler(),numeric_columns),
    ('cat',LabelBinarizer(),categorical_columns),
])

new_X=pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```