# Pipelining transformer stages in IBEX, column access problems in Scikit-Learn and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a scikit-learn based pipeline to pipeline through a pandas dataframe. At each stage, only a subset of features should be touched, the rest should pass through unmodified. I'm using IBEX for this since DataFrameMapper doesn't seem to do the job for me since the untouched fields are not retained, for sake of completeness, here the DataFrameMapper code (which is NOT working for me, but maybe fore someone else):

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    (['x','y','z'], StandardScaler())
])

df_scaled = mapper.fit_transform(df)
```

The dataframe has following fields

> x     y   z   source  class

Using IBEX I run the following code:

```
from ibex.sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from ibex.sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from ibex import trans

pipeline = (trans(LabelEncoder(), in_cols=['class']) + trans(None, ['source', 'x','y','z'])) | (trans(StandardScaler(), in_cols=['x','y','z']) + trans(None, ['source', 'class']))
df_scaled = pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

Now I get the following error since it seems that the fields are not retained in the 2nd pipeline stage:

> KeyError: "['x' 'y' 'z'] not in index"

See [GIST](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/22dc787728680d46e12bc3c825274123) of complete error

Comment: I think, the bahaviour that you have observed with `DataFrameMapper` follows the class documentation on [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas). It is expected to output transformed columns only. One would need to do a `FeatureUnion` on `DataFrameMapper` together with another transformer returning the complementary subset of other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ibex`](https://github.com/atavory/ibex) (which I co-wrote) makes extensive use of Pandas multilevel indexes.

Suppose we start with

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'source': [2, 44], 'class': [0, 1], 'x': [0, 5], 'y': [0, 6], 'z': [0, 8], 'w': 10})
>>> df
   class  source   w  x  y  z
0      0       2  10  0  0  0
1      1      44  10  5  6  8
```

Then the beginning of your pipeline gives

```
>>> (trans(LabelEncoder(), in_cols=['class']) + trans(None, ['source', 'x','y','z'])).fit_transform(df)
    functiontransformer_0   functiontransformer_1
    0                       source  x   y   z
0   0                       2       0   0   0
1   1                       44      5   6   8
```

This is by design.

You can achieve what you want by writing the pipeline as:

```
p = (
    trans(LabelEncoder(), in_cols="class")
    + trans(StandardScaler(), in_cols=["x", "y", "z"])
    + trans(None, in_cols="source")
)
>>> p.fit_transform(df)
    functiontransformer_0   functiontransformer_1   functiontransformer_2
    0                       x        y         z    source
0   0                       -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    2
1   1                       1.0     1.0     1.0     44
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I got a new one for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351225/how-to-access-multi-level-index-in-ibex-transformer-pipeline