# Using Python to KNN: What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I am working on a class assignment where I need to use KNN to construct  a classifier and report accuracy. I have some code I have been working on. I received this error on the code below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\jazzm\OneDrive\Desktop\python\HWK6.py", line 20, in 
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
File "C:\Users\jazzm\OneDrive\Desktop\python.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_classification.py", line 207, in fit
return self._fit(X, y)
File "C:\Users\jazzm\OneDrive\Desktop\python.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_base.py", line 429, in _fit
check_classification_targets(y)
File "C:\Users\jazzm\OneDrive\Desktop\python.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 200, in check_classification_targets
raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

```
import pandas as PD
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mtp

data_set= PD.read_csv('hw6.data.csv.gz')

x= data_set.iloc[:,[2,3]].values
y= data_set.iloc[:, 4].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x,y, test_size=.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
st_x= StandardScaler()
x_train= st_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test= st_x.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred= classifier.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

the values that you use for the response variable are continuous instead of categorical.

Comment: What in my code should I change to make it categorical?

Comment: read this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-cut-continuous-to-categorical/

Answer (score 0):

The main goals are as follows:

1. Apply StandardScaler to continuous variables
2. Apply LabelEncoder and OnehotEncoder to categorical variables

please read : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554821/feature-preprocessing-of-both-continuous-and-categorical-variables-of-integer-t)